# Alternative to virtual template methods in C++

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

Suppose that you have an abstract template class `IParser` that has a virtual method called `parse` that should parse a string and return an object of template type.

You have another abstract class `INetlinkAdapter` that is representing an adapter for Netlink communication ad it provides a virtual method to send a request and parse its reply using an `IParser`.

So something like the following:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct IParser<T> {
   std::shared_ptr<T> parse(std::string_view message) const;
};

struct INetlinkAdapter {
   template<typename T>
   virtual std::shared_ptr<T> sendRequestAndParseReply(int request, const IParser<T> & replyPparser);
};
```

This would be invalid since it is not possible to have virtual template methods in C++.

So I was wondering which could be an elegant and robust solution for this architectural problem.

Comment: Why does `INetlinkAdapter` need to be an interface at all?

Comment: Pre-C++20, I think you just want a template function and to let the template code generation deal with the fallout. In C++20, you can probably express this type neatly with concepts and get a lot nicer error messages.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve: do you want `INetlinkAdapter*` with descendant implementations callable via base ptr, or do you simply want to ensure that descendants implement the method?

Comment: @lorro the first one

Comment: @PatrickRoberts because of "code against interfaces, not implementations" principle, so to keep my code decoupled from a particular implementation

Comment: @KillKRT `std::variant<Impl1, Impl2, ...>` and `std::visit()`, then.

Comment: @KillKRT virtual polymorphism tends to be overused in "OO" paradigm, when it is often the case that the implementation is already known at compile-time. As was already stated, concepts are a good way to enforce a particular interface at compile-time without the unnecessary overhead of virtual methods.

Comment: This might be interesting for you: https://youtu.be/gTNJXVmuRRA

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I do in these situations is I forget the C++ object model exists.  Pretend there is no `virtual`.

C++ remains a full featured OO language without it, you just have to do inheritance the C way.

Our parser is just a function from bytes to an object instance.  (The shared ptr requirement is implementation leak).

The network link adapter takes a request, produces bytes, then feeds it to the parser, which produces the object instance.

At this point you should see we are doing composition of functions.

So we rewrite our code to know this.

```
struct bytes; // some stream of bytes 
template<class T>
using parser=std::function<std::shared_ptr<T>(bytes)>;

struct request;

using ByteProvider=std::function<bytes(request)>;

tenplate<class T>
using DataProvider=std::function<std::shared_ptr<T>(request)>;

template<class T>
DataProvider<T> GetDataProvider(ByteProvider b, Parser<T> p){
  return [=](request r)){
    return p(b(r));
  };
}
```

We can rewrite this OO style by having a template method that does the bytes-to-parser in the interface, and pure virtual methods that do the bytes.